# security trimming for end user for SharePoint search result from a system user

Tags: c#, security, sharepoint

Basically we have an iOS app and also a Server application. iOS app would like to get some search result for the end user from SharePoint, so iOS app would submit search request to our server application which would perform the search by using web services (client API) on SharePoint by using a system account. The problem for us is to how to do the security trimming of search results for end user on iOS app.

We could send up the end user's user name and password from iOS app to our server and use that credential to call the search web services, however it is not desirable to do so. I also looked the custom security trimming (CST, [Trim SharePoint Search Results for Better Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796226.aspx) at SharePoint, it looks like that it won't solve our problem since at ISecurityTrimmer2:CheckAccess method, there is the claims for user who performed the query which is a system user, however we would need to be able to call our application back to find out the real user which seems not practical here:

> public BitArray CheckAccess(IListdocumentCrawlUrls, IDictionarysessionProperties, IIdentitypassedUserIdentity)

Any other thoughts about how we could implement the trimming here for our situation? It is really appreciated for any suggestions.

By the way, the iOS app does use the SharePoint Web Services directly, however we want to avoid that since we want the API for search to be generic and not be limited to SharePoint, we are also thinking about sending the authentication header/cookie from iOS app to server for search, however it seems to me that it might not be a good idea and could be think of a security hack.

Update 1:
based on this post: [Security trimming in search web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100792/security-trimming-in-search-web-service) and [Creating a Custom Pre-Security Trimmer for SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/security_trimming_in_sharepoint_2013/archive/2012/10/30/creating-a-custom-pre-security-trimmer.aspx), there is ISecurityTrimmerPre which we could add more claims to the user, in theory, it could call back our web services to add the claims the correct end user although I don't really know how it would know which end user this search is for if there are multiple searches going on the same time. Another worry is that it seems that we would affect general SharePoint search as well which we don't want to do since we are adding ourselves to the search query pipeline.

Comment: Maybe you can try to check in custom security trimmer if IIdentity is particular account (some custom account which you create to call search service application from your app) and if it is then try to use some seesion parameters or something like that.

Comment: thanks @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets. You mean that we could set the end user name plus his claims at the session properties and then replace those on IIdentitypassedUserIdentity, right? Does search API allow us to set any arbitrary data when issuing the search? I guess we would have to try it out to see.

Comment: Also maybe you should take a look at sharepoint oauth.

Comment: based on this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142384.aspx for SharePoint oauth, it says "If it is an OAuth call, SharePoint 2013 uses the Windows Azure Access Control Service (ACS) as the app identity provider." so it seems not mean for the windows AD credential.

Comment: Look at this post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj687470.aspx. Basically with OAuth you redirect user to SharePoint site where user login using his credential after what he is redirected back to you app. At this point your app gets access token which is used to access data on sharepoint.

Comment: thanks, this is not a pressing issue any more, however thanks very much for the information and will revisit again later.